# How to store this in database mysql PHP jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an ul & li and I've made this sortable with jquery. 
I am able to get the array of it by doing the following:

```
update: function () {
                var data = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                console.log(data); 

            }
```

In Firebug, I see the following output:

***["experience", "skills", "about-yourself", "teaching-experience", "education", "languages", "publications", "patents", "talks", "certifications", "awards"]***

Can I store this as it is in the mysql, or how shall this exactly be stored?

Shall the DB Table be like this:

**sort_order_table**

**id AUTOINCREMENT,**

**Order_array,**

**userID,**

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot.

***EDIT: I PLAN TO RELOAD THE STORED ORDER AND RENDER THE LIST FOR THE USER.***

Comment: The answer depends upon how you're planning to use the stored data in the future...

Comment: I plan, to load the order, and render the list in the order it was saved by the user. Currently, update in jquery sortable, allows to live update the array.

Comment: You're going to need a field that stores the order.  By default you can't assume a database will return items in any particular order

Comment: I am aware of that, I want to store the ABOVE output into a database, and the reload that output the way it was initially stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it as `JSON` in the database, but that has a few drawbacks. For example, if you'd want to get the count of the `JSON Array`, you'll need to get the row, parse the `JSON` and then count the elements. I would usually insert the values into a database table.

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_sort (
    id       integer    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id  integer,   -- is this order associated with an user?
    value    varchar(255)
);
```

When you send the request to save sorted data, in the php scrip you'd have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_sort(user_id, value) VALUES(1, 'experience');
INSERT INTO my_sort(user_id, value) VALUES(1, 'skills');
-- and so on
```

Afterwards, when selecting the data to output it in your UI, you would simply do:

```
SELECT value FROM my_sort ORDER BY id ASC;
```

And then convert it into a JSON object if necessary.

In your javascript, you would need to have something similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://link.com/to/your/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sortables: $('#sortable').sortable('toArray')
    }
})
```

In the `script.php` you would have something similar to this:

```
<?php

    // this will contain an array with all of your sortables in the order they were 
    $sortables = $_POST['sortables'];

    // delete all elements saved for the current user. I assume your user_id is stored in the session - if it's not, change $_SESSION['user_id'] to the variable that holds the user_id
    // DELETE FROM my_sort WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    foreach($sortables as $sortable) {
         // here you would execute the INSERT. 
         // INSERT INTO my_sort(user_id, value) VALUES($_SESSION['user_id'], $sortable);
    }

?>
```

The code above is not tested, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Re: -- is this order associated with an user?, YES it is.

Comment: How is this exactly stored? It looks very messy, sorry if I sound rude, but I am trying to figure out a way to store this in a very efficient way. I've searched the web for two days now, with no good results.

Comment: Can I store it like this:  " ["experience", "skills", "about-yourself", "teaching-experience", "education", "languages", "publications", "patents", "talks", "certifications", "awards"] "

Comment: You're posting a JSON array object. You need to pass that via `$.post` or an ajax query to your server-side script, which would then require the loop I described.

Comment: The INSERT INTO my_sort(user_id, value) VALUES(1, 'experience'); while it does these inserts, does it fill out many rows, or is it in one tuple?

Comment: @JohnSmith I will give you a working example in about 30minutes as I'm not home right now

Comment: The problem I am having, is the database not the PHP nor the jquery code, but the database tables and saving etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The `sortables` will be saved one by one in the database - every sortable entry will have a new row in the table. You could save them as a JSON as well, but as I said in my answer, it has a few drawbacks. If you'd like I could give you and example with that as well.

Comment: Good, you've used $_SESSION in the example, will this approach allow expansion, for example, there can be other sections as well. Each of these sections, e.g. Experience is another table in the Database holding other lists.

Comment: Sure, just add a new column in the database, i.e. `sort_type` containing the name of the section and then you could save/retrieve `sortables` for that certain section.

Comment: Will this allow more sections, for example: Research, some sections can be disabled by default until the user decides to enable and save with the sort order.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I guess that might work. You should try and see.

Answer (score 1):

Updating my answer based on our discussion.

You have:

- A list of values that website users need to be able to sort.
- Each user needs a way to sort the list for themselves only

Pseudo-code db schema:

```
values table: `value_id`, `value_name`

userSort table: `user_id`, `value_id`, `sort_order`
```

Sample query to load the data:

```
select value_id, value_name, sort_order from values
join userSort on userSort.value_id = values.value_id
order by sort_order, value_name
```

Example html (using the results of the above query to populate):

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Example javascript:

```
// when you detect the user has sorted, post the values to the server:
$.post('yourScript.php', { data: $(this).sortable('toArray') } );
```

i.e. in pseudo code:

```
query('delete from userSorts where user_id = ' . (int) $user_id);

int i = 0;
for( item in data ){
  query('insert into userSorts (user_id,value_id,sort_order) VALUES ( $user_id, "item.value_id", i ) );
  i++
}
```

You'll need to adapt this for you chosen database and server-side language, and you should ensure your javascript is sending the value_id as well as the value, otherwise you'll need to do some sort of lookup on the server end.

Comment: I see your pseudo code, but the way you tell me via this pseudo code doesn't seem like a perfect solution, I would like you to confirm if my solution is OK or not, and what is a better approach that you are aware of - with the exception of what you have already posted.

Comment: The point is you need to store the sort_order value somewhere but you need to have to associated with the value you're sorting. That means you need to have original ul/li content stored in the db to begin with. When you send the JSON object to the server-side code it's going to be an array, meaning you need to iterate the values and generate a new sort order

Comment: Sure, you're right regarding the pre-stored order. But I want to store it the way it's outputted, as you can see above.

Comment: That's why I wrote my answer. Send the `$(this).sortable('toArray')` data to your server-side script - that's the exact order the data is currently in. The `loop` on the server-side will iterate them in the exact same order, so you just need to generate a new `sort_order` and update the db. I've used this method numerous times

Comment: When looped as you suggest, how is it exactly stored then?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. My pseudo code explains the process. On the server-side you need to loop the array and update your database for the given value and set a new sort order number.

Comment: Can't it just be stored like this: " ["experience", "skills", "about-yourself", "teaching-experience", "education", "languages", "publications", "patents", "talks", "certifications", "awards"]  "

Comment: You *can* store the JSON string but that's not how databases should be used. What happens if a value changes? If these are stored in the database to begin with you can change the value there, and the sort order is left intact. If the text value here stops matching the text value on the site, your sort order breaks.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean I shall have a sort_order_ID, like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Crk.jpg

Comment: Combining my example of server-side code and @tftd example of the schema and you'd literally have the feature complete.

Comment: I see. But I cannot wrap my head around this, because I plan to load this information from Database, and each user must see their list in their own order (the way they ordered it), but I am unable to see how that looks on the DB side and with the PHP.

Comment: Updated my answer to show you a more completed example based on your comments

Comment: The problem I am having, is the database not the PHP nor the jquery code, but the database tables and saving etc. Your latest information is interesting.

Comment: Why would you need the `sort_order` column ? You could simply use the `auto_increment` primary key for that purpose?

Comment: You're right, the end result would be the same. The only reason an extra col is needed is if you want to adjust the sort values individually in any situation you don't want to reset the group.